# Multipart/form-data in a POST call with BASIC AUTH in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, post, basic-authentication

I need to do a POST call that sends a file (Multipart/form-data) to an API with basic auth, from a process as client, not web application, with this code:

```
 public static void sendFile(){
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = createHeaders("admin","admin");
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(REST_SERVICE_URL_ACCEPT_FILE,
            HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
```

But I alwais get a 401 response, the code in the server side is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/healthCheck").permitAll()      //Fails with POST
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/loginOnly").authenticated()   //Works with GET
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/processFile").authenticated() //Cant with GET
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .httpBasic();
}


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
      .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
}
```

How could I call the API? Testing with Postman, I also get the 401 response. Can I be able to make the basic auth request or is better switch the auth method? The client should have the lesser number of libraries as possible.

Thanks for reading and time.

Comment: Were you able to overcome this? I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I was abled, just remade all the configuration step by step splitting in the simplest use case, checking it did work, and then adding the next step. I don't remember what caused the problem